# View content of the field in the mouse transition in JS

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I have a pop up in which I have a field that is selected the name of a lawyer where I can choose from a list and when I choose there are more fields that are automatically filled with the data like lawyer address phone lawyer etc.
But sometimes the value is longer than the field and you do not see the whole value
I want that when the mouse is on the field it will basically display all the value that is inside

I wrote the following code in JS:

```
    $('#editLawSuitModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(".addressTooltip").tooltip();
    $('.addressTooltip').tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'Password tooltip' });
});

$(document).on('change', '#legal-lawyerChoose', function () {
    $(".addressTooltip").tooltip();
    $('.addressTooltip').tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'Password tooltip' });
});
```

I did this both in editing the pop-up and in adding a new one
And of course I put in every field I wanted to operate on it I did a DIV with this data:

class="col-md-6 addressTooltip" data-title="@Model.LawyerOffice"

When I edit a pop up it works great and when I create a new one it does not work
I thought maybe it's because it loads the CSHTML page before it's in JS and when I created a new pop up it basically has nothing inside the data so it's like just
But I do not know if it is really like that and if so what can I do for him to load the data that is inside after he chooses a lawyer there?
Does anyone know how to help me with this?